# Excluindo pelo button

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

bom dia galera, estou usando js com php, o problema que estou tento é que eu não estou conseguindo entender de como passar para o button e o script, segue abaixo a onde eu parei.

index.php

```
<button class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger right ml3" id="removerRegistro"></button>
```

removerRegistro.php

```
<?php
require "conexao.php";

if(isset($_GET["cli_id"]) && empty($_GET["cli_id"])){

    $cli_id = $_GET["cli_id"]; 

    $conex = new conexao();

    $conex->deleteDesc($_GET["id"]);          

}
```

Conexao.php

```
public function deleteDesc($cli_id){
        $sql = $this->conexao->prepare("DELETE FROM descricao WHERE cli_id = :cli_id");
        $sql->bindValue(':cli_id', $cli_id);
        $sql->execute();
    }
```

Ajax
removerRegistro.php

```
<?php 
require_once "../database/conexao.php";

if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])){

        $conex = new conexao();

    retun json_encode($conex->deleteDesc($_GET["id"]));
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).on('click','#removerRegistro', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
})

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/removerRegistro.php?id=' + id,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done((e) => {

})
```

Comment: Seu `script.js` não faz muito sentido. Ele está assim mesmo? Pois no clique do botão você apenas atribui a variável `id`, mas não faz nada com ela; além disso você tenta utilizar o valor de `id` fora do evento para fazer a requisição e isso não fez sentido.

Comment: Nesta condição, `isset($_GET["cli_id"]) && empty($_GET["cli_id"])`, acredito que faltou o `!` na frente do `empty`. Aliás, não é necessário utilizar `isset` e `empty` juntos, pois o próprio `empty` verifica se a variável está definida. Veja a documentação para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que colocar o AJAX dentro do evento para poder pegar a variável `id` e fazer a requisição, já que, pelo visto, isso só deve ocorrer no click do botão. E falta colocar o atributo `data-id` no botão com o valor do id que você quer passar.

O button seria:

```
<button data-id="VALOR DO ID" class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger right ml3" id="removerRegistro"></button>
         ↑↑↑↑↑
```

E o código do evento:

```
$(document).on('click','#removerRegistro', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

   $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/removerRegistro.php?id=' + id,
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'JSON'
   }).done((e) => {

   })
})
```

> Não precisa colocar `type: 'GET',`. GET já é o método padrão do AJAX.

Comment: ainda nada resolvido... arrumei algumas coisas, mas não esta achando o id...

Comment: Oi Fernando. Onde está o id que vc quer pegar? No button não tem nenhum atributo `data-id`.

Comment: <button class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger right ml3" id="removerRegistro" v-bind:data-id="descricao.cli_id"></button>